# Iter built in function with classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class Kids():
    def __init__(self, list_of_kids):
        self.kids = list_of_kids

    def __next__(self):
        return 'kawabanga'
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

kid = Kids([1,2,3])
kids_iter = iter(kid)
print(kid)
print(kids_iter)
print(iter([1,2,3]))
```

I've built the code above as an example.
I receive the following output:

```
<__main__.Kids object at 0x102977b38>
<__main__.Kids object at 0x102977b38>
<list_iterator object at 0x102977be0>
```

As far as I understand: `iter()` should return an iterator object, but as you can see when I enter the function `iter()` the object `Kids` it returns a `Kids` object instead of an iterator object.

Can you please explain me why it doesn't return an iterator object when I call `iter()` on the object `Kids`?

Comment: Well, your `__iter__` method *does* return `self`. That means that `Kids` instances are *themselves* iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are overwriting `iter()` behaviour when setting `__iter__` on the class. As you can see, you return self, so you basically redefined what `iter(Kids)` does.

The correct way to implement this is to `yield`, instead of `return` in `__iter__`. This of course only makes sense if you plan on combining it with something like a for loop, so that you iterate over multiple objects. Otherwise `__iter__` and `__next__` will only ever give you a single object instance.

Answer (score 3):

Because you return `self` from `Kids.__iter__` and not a special `iterator` object as `list` objects do (`list_iterator`).

Your class *is* itself the iterator since it defines `__iter__` and `__next__`.

If, instead, you want to handle the iteration at a separate object for the `Kids` class (and there's plenty of reasons to want to do that), create a `Kids_Iterator` object that defines `__iter__` and `__next__` and make `Kids.__iter__` return a new instance of the `Kids_Iterator` class.